# XPath - Return child nodes but not descendants

Tags: c#, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML.

```
<Programme>
    <Intakes>
        <One>
            <Information />
        </One>
        <Two>
            <Information />
        </Two>
    </Intakes>
</Programme>
```

Wanted result information inside the listbox:

```
One
Two
```

Basically I wish to populate a list box with an option for each intake (one, two, etc).

does not have multiple occurances.

So I do not get individual intakes child nodes?

Current code:

```
        XPathNavigator nav;
        XPathDocument docNav;
        XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;
        string strExpression;

        docNav = new XPathDocument(docPath);
        nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();

        strExpression = "//Intakes/node()";
        NodeIter = nav.Select(strExpression);

        while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
        {
            lstIntakes.Items.Add(NodeIter.Current.Value);
        }
```

However this only adds one item to the listbox containing all the xml from inside the  node.

Comment: It is not very clear, if you have multiple `Intakes` nodes and you want to combine them? or you want to eliminate the `Information` nodes

Comment: Yep, clarify please. And update expected result. Thanks!

Comment: Please explain why you are trying to do this. XPath is used to select nodesets. When you select `//Intakes/*` for example, you are returning the `<One>` and `<Two>` nodes for further processing. You can ignore further children. If you want to *remove* further children and persist that to a file, then you're going beyond the capacity of pure XPath.

Comment: Yes, you're wanting to use a tool designed for **selection** (XPath) and in order to do **transformation**, which is more the realm of XSLT (or perhaps LINQ to XML). As @MarkThomas says, once you've selected `Intakes`, you have necessarily selected its entire children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**XPath is a query language for XML documents and as such it cannot alter the structure of a document**.

**XSLT is a proper tool for transforming an XML document into another**. The XSLT solution of this problem is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="One/node()|Two/node()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Programme>
    <Intakes>
        <One>
            <Information />
        </One>
        <Two>
            <Information />
        </Two>
    </Intakes>
</Programme>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Intakes>
   <One/>
   <Two/>
</Intakes>
```

**UPDATE**: The OP has changed the question radically -- now the wanted result is:

```
One  
Two
```

This still cannot be provided by a single XPath 1.0 expression (and as you are using C#, you probably don't have access to an XPath 2.0 implementation).

**You have first to select all children elements of `Intakes`:**

```
/*/Intakes/*
```

**Then you have to iterate through the returned node-set and for each element contained in it evaluate this XPath expression**:

```
name()
```

Comment: Clarified my question while you were answering Dimitre, it was written in a rush and I realise now it gave the complete wrong impression of what I wanted

Comment: @Mike: No problem -- I have updated the answer -- does this show how to solve the problem?